# Javascript - iterating through HTML collection

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to remove an entire HTML collection from the DOM. I used the Array.from to create an array of the HTML collection. When I try to iterate through the array it shows up as blank. My expectation was for it to show each individual node through the loop so I could remove each one individually.

My first question is why I am not able to access the array like I normally would. The second question is the best practice for iterating through an HTML collection. My code is listed below. Thank you

**Update - For clarification, I am trying to delete all of the divs on the div with the id of 'grid' when the user clicks 'Dimensions Choice'. At this point the user can input new dimensions and fill the grid back up.

specific block of code in question

```
    if (button.className == undefined || button.className == false) {
        button.className = 'true';
    } else if (button.className == 'true') {
        let divList = document.querySelectorAll('.divs');
        let arrayList = Array.from(divList);
        console.log('array List', arrayList)
        console.log('arrayList[0]', arrayList[0]);
        for (i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++) {
            console.log(arrayList[i]);
        }
    }

    gridSize = prompt('What grid size would you like?')
    fillGrid(gridSize);
})
```

```
const body = document.getElementById('body');
const sketchPad = document.getElementById('etch-a-sketch');
const button = document.getElementById('userSelection');
const grid = document.getElementById('grid');

button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

    if (button.className == undefined || button.className == false) {
        button.className = 'true';
    } else if (button.className == 'true') {
        let divList = document.querySelectorAll('.divs');
        let arrayList = Array.from(divList);
        console.log('array List', arrayList)
        console.log('arrayList[0]', arrayList[0]);
        for (i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++) {
            console.log(arrayList[i]);
        }
    }

    gridSize = prompt('What grid size would you like?')
    fillGrid(gridSize);
})

function createGrid(gridFill) {

    grid.setAttribute('style', `display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(${gridFill}, 1fr); height: 100%; width: 100%;
    background-color: white;`);
}

function fillGrid(gridSize) {

    createGrid(gridSize)

    for (i = 0; i < gridSize * gridSize; i++) {
        let div = document.createElement('div');
        div.classList.add('divs');
        grid.appendChild(div);
    }

}

grid.addEventListener("mouseover", (e) => {
    function random256() {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * 257);
    }
    function color() {
        return `rgb(${random256()},${random256()},${random256()})`;
    }
    color();
})
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="etch-a-sketch.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" />
  </head>
  <body id="body">
    <h1 id="title">Etch-A-Sketch</h1>
    <button id="userSelection">Dimensions Choice</button>
    <div id="etch-a-sketch">
      <div id="grid"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="etch-a-sketch.js"></script>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body,
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#title {
  text-align: center;
}

#userSelection {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#etch-a-sketch {
  width: 640px;
  height: 640px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.divs {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: `button.className == undefined` will always be `false`. `button.className == false` is a cumbersome way of checking `button.className === ""`, which itself is an old-fashioned way of checking `button.classList.length === 0`. `button.className` is a _string_, never a boolean or undefined. Also, `false != "false"`.

Comment: Using `.querySelectorAll('.divs')` matches all elements having a class named "divs"; to match all `div` elements instead, use `.querySelectorAll('div')` for a static list, or `.getElementsByTagName('div')` for a live list. There's probably no need to convert to an Array if you're not using any "fancy" Array methods (but I guess converting probably won't hurt anything either). The easiest way to loop through DOM elements may be to use the [`for...of` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#iterating_over_a_dom_collection).

Comment: Where and when are you `"attempting to remove an entire HTML collection from the DOM"`? I see nothing in the above code that attempts to remove anything from the DOM

Comment: I am trying to remove all of the divs from the Grid when a user clicks 'Dimensions Choice'. At this point they can put in new dimensions and the grid can fill up with those amount of 'Divs'.

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear where you wished to `"remove an entire HTML collection from the DOM"` but I assumed it was in the button click handler but I may have missed the point and I got a little carried away playing with this but I hope you find use in it

```js
const sketchPad = document.getElementById('etch-a-sketch');
const button = document.getElementById('userSelection');
const grid = document.getElementById('grid');

const clearcells=false;
const maxsize=50;
let tx=NaN;


const bttnclickhandler=(e)=>{
  togglevalue(e);
  if( !e.target.classList.contains('active') ){
    let col=document.querySelectorAll('.divs');

    if( !isNaN(tx) )clearTimeout(tx);
    col.forEach((div,i)=>{
      tx=setTimeout(()=>{
        if( div.nodeType==1 )grid.removeChild( div )
      }, 50 * i * ( 1 / col.length ) );
    });

    grid.style.backgroundColor='inherit';
    clearsize(e);
  }else{
    gridSize = prompt( 'What grid size would you like?' );
    if( !isNaN( gridSize ) && gridSize!=null ) {
      if( gridSize > maxsize )gridSize=maxsize;
      fillGrid( gridSize );
      showsize(e);
    }
  }
};

const mouseoverhandler=(e)=>{
  function random256() { return Math.floor(Math.random() * 257); };
  function color() { rgb( random256(), random256(), random256() ) };
  const rgb=(r,g,b)=>{ e.target.style.backgroundColor='rgba('+r+','+g+','+b+')'; };
  if( grid.childNodes.length > 0 ) color();     
};

const mouseouthandler=(e)=>{
  if( clearcells )e.target.style.backgroundColor='inherit';
};

function createGrid(gridFill) {
  grid.setAttribute('style', `display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(${gridFill}, 1fr); height: 100%; width: 100%;
  background-color: white;`);
};

function fillGrid(gridSize) {
  createGrid( gridSize );
  for( i = 0; i < gridSize * gridSize; i++ ) {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.classList.add('divs');
    grid.appendChild(div);
  }
};

const showsize=e=>{e.target.previousElementSibling.textContent=[gridSize,gridSize].join(' x ')}
const clearsize=e=>{e.target.previousElementSibling.textContent='';}

const togglevalue=(e)=>{
  e.target.classList.toggle('active');
  e.target.dataset.tmp=e.target.textContent;
  e.target.textContent=e.target.dataset.alt;
  e.target.dataset.alt=e.target.dataset.tmp;
  delete e.target.dataset.tmp
}



grid.addEventListener("mouseover",mouseoverhandler);
grid.addEventListener("mouseout",mouseouthandler);
button.addEventListener("click",bttnclickhandler);
```

```css
body,
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family:fantasy;
}
#title {
  text-align: center;
}
#userSelection {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#etch-a-sketch {
  width: 640px;
  height: 640px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.divs {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1#title + span{
  float:none;
  display:block;
  margin:0.25rem auto;
  width:10%;
  text-align:center;
  padding:1rem;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Etch-A-Sketch</h1>
<span></span>

<button id="userSelection" data-alt='Clear'>Dimensions Choice</button>
<div id="etch-a-sketch">
  <div id="grid"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain it well enough. I am trying to remove the divs from the "grid" to do a refresh. So that when a user clicks the 'Dimension Choice' it will delete all of the divs so they can input new dimensions.

Comment: Have a try with the code above... run the snippet to test

Answer (score 0):

I made the following changes below and it worked.

```
function refresh() {
    let divs = document.querySelectorAll('.divs');
    for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        divs[i].remove()
    }
}

button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

    refresh()

    gridSize = prompt('What grid size would you like?')
    fillGrid(gridSize);
})
```